# Reverse routing with optional GET parameters in Play Framework

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.2

I'm using scala 2.10 and playframework 2.2.1

Lets assume following routing:

```
GET    /users/page/:page/limit/:limit    controllers.Users.showUsers(page: Int, limit: Int)
```

I'd like to add search form with `GET` method and few fields and also add some pagination. 
For example, after form submission url will look like this:

http://example.com/users/page/1/limit/20?login=someLogin&email=

To avoid url hardcoding in pagination code I'm using reverse routing such as `@routes.Users.showUsers(currentPage, limit)` inside my template. Is it possible to add also GET parameters to resulting url without some ugly code like `fold` through `Form` inside template, etc?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, kind of. Optional route parameters have been removed in Play 2.2, so you have to define default values for pagination parameters. The reverse router will know how to fill them in.

```
GET    /users/page/:page/limit/:limit       controllers.Users.showUsers(page: Int, limit: Int, login: String ?= "", email: String ?= "")

object Users extends Controller {

     def showUsers(page: Int, limit: Int, login: String = "", email: String = "") {
          // show those users..
     }
}
```

`@routes.Users.showUsers(3, 20, "someLogin")` would produce the URL: `/users/page/3/limit/20?login=someLogin`

Not particularly pretty, but better than hard-coding URLs.

Comment: Ye, its kinda okay. But as far as I see, there is no chances to use just a `Form` to handle all those GET params from request instead of manual routung.

Comment: How do you mean? If you could explain what you want to do a little more, it might be possible.

Comment: For example, i dont have to put login and email fields manually to routes.conf and `showUsers` in case of creating `Form` from request with an implicit variant of `bindFromRequest` inside of `showUsers`. Lets imagine that I have 22 fields inside of my form. 22 arguments inside of routes.conf and 22 arguments for showUsers. Its kinda awful

Comment: I still don't really understand what you want to do. If don't want to have 22 parameters in your GET request, then you could use a `Form` or even json as the request body. Either way, you'll have to `fold` the request body. That isn't considered ugly at all, it's a nice way of handling errors. There are other ways to extract parameters, but those are 10 times more ugly. Based on what you've described though, I don't know enough.

Comment: I want to use `Form` for 22 params and add those params to pagination hrefs without fold etc, just using reverse routing or may be another simple way. But seems like its impossible.